# i want varable in two equal parts

Tags: php

fetching some data from mysqli

```
$value=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
```

I have a result like

```
$value = "123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930";
```

but I want to use it two variables like

```
$value1 = "123456789101112131415";
$value2 = "161718192021222324252627282930";
```

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt, so we can help you on your way?

Comment: i have tried array_chunks andarray slice as well...but not working

Comment: `while($val=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`
`{foreach ($val as $key => $value) { `

`?>`

`<tr>`
`<td><?php echo $key;?></td>`
`<td><?php echo $value1;}}?></td>`

Comment: so you're echoing the strings, but how did you try to process the strings? Are the strings all / always the same shape?

Comment: i want to show the data in a html table in different <td>'s...............actually i am fetching two rows from sql and  want output in one table only

Comment: https://www.ubtpro.in/international-courier-usa.php ....pls chk

Comment: Sounds like this has no relevant connection to the fetching of the data at all, but you simply want to split a string value (by some logic/rules you neglected to tell us _anything_ about so far) … so please next time try to actually phrase your question accordingly. Having the title read “devide the fetch result in two equal parts” is just misleading. Don’t give unnecessary info that is completely irrelevant to the actual problem that needs solving.

Comment: i ralized that i m doing many mistakes here.....can u pls help me with the issue

Comment: You need to rework your question - make it clear what you're trying to achieve exactly, and show us the actual(best attempt) vs. the desired outcome.

Comment: https://www.ubtpro.in/international-courier-usa.php pls have a look on this page ...it has a table ....the output is coming from a variable....two data rows in a variable .....i m just stuckup at how to show both the rows seperately in different <td>

Comment: If you were my student I would demand you to write 10000 times on a blackboard that `123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930`. Every number in a different color. In the exact sequence. ‍♂️ How can you possibly expect one to understand the splitting logic by reading such a question?

Comment: Thanks Roko C. Buljan but as of now i m not in the right frame of mind.....as i have asked in many ways ....may be there is a problem with me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the database column names.
If you don't have the value you need in separate database column you have to somehow extract the value from an existing column.
You can use `substr` or regex to do so.

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['DATABASE_COLUMN_1_NAME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DATABASE_COLUMN_2_NAME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DATABASE_COLUMN_3_NAME']; ?></td>
    <!-- show only a part of the db columns content -->
    <?php $valueIwantToShow = subtr($row['DATABASE_COLUMN_4_NAME'], 0, 5); ?>
    <td><?php echo valueIwantToShow; ?></td>
    <!-- or show multiple values in one html column -->
    <td><?php echo $row['DATABASE_COLUMN_6_NAME']; ?>, <?php echo $row['DATABASE_COLUMN_7_NAME']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i m fetching data in loop and each value of variable has 4 to 5 digits ...i have tried strlen but its making variable value only first two digits......

Comment: If it's a loop, how is your DB structured? And what do you want to get at the end?

Comment: https://ubtpro.in/test.txt pls check the code ...i didnt try to transpose the table as i got the desired result....but i just stucked in the last moment where i have to show the both rows seperately

Comment: I edited the answer, is that what you are looking for? I think you can skip the  $valueIwantToShow stuff because it looks like you have all values in separate database columns

Comment: My Dear sfeldmann, first of all i really appreciate your efforts....second if u see the DB structure at https://ubtpro.in/db.jpg and the only 2 ids data required....most of the people advised me to transpose the table but i think this is the easy way....

Comment: i just want the `<?php echo $row['DATABASE_COLUMN_1_NAME']; ?>` in two seperate variables